# Prolog - Cartesian product calculator

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, cartesian-product

I need to create a Cartesian product calculator for Prolog. It should work like this:

Input: `product([1,2,3], [a,b], X).`

Output: `X = [[1,a],[2,a],[3,a],[1,b],[2,b],[3,b]].`

I know there are examples on the Internet, but I wanted to write something myself.

This is my code and I think it's pretty close, but for some reason it doesn't exactly work. Any ideas, guys?

```
% call new with 4 parameters (so we can keep List1 in memory)
product(L1,L2,L3):- product(L1,L2,L3,L1).

% stop when both List1 and List2 are empty
product([], [], [], []).

% first list is empty, recreate it and work it again with the next element of second list (and shorten memory)
product([], [_|T2], List3, [H4|T4]):-
    product([H4|T4], T2, List3, T4).

%go through first list and always first element of second list to our answer
product([H1|T1], [H2|T2], [[H1,H2]|T3], List4):-
    product(T1, [H2|T2], T3, List4).
```

Comment: Of interest: [Combinations of multiple lists - Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60820671/1243762) answer by repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by Coder (+1), you should change the terminal clause from

```
product([], [], [], []).
```

to

```
product(_, [], [], _).
```

But isn't enough.

You should change the third clause from

```
product([], [_|T2], List3, [H4|T4]):-
    product([H4|T4], T2, List3, T4).
```

to

```
product([], [_|T2], List3, L4):-
    product(L4, T2, List3, L4).
```

I mean: is an error to consume the saved list 1.

With your version, from

```
product([1,2,3,4,5], [a,b,c,d], X),
```

you get only

```
[[1,a],[2,a],[3,a],[4,a],[5,a],[1,b],[2,b],[3,b],[4,b],[5,b],[2,c],[3,c],[4,c],[5,c],[3,d],[4,d],[5,d]]
```

That is: you loose `[1,c]`, `[1,d]` and `[2,d]`.

Answer (score 7):

In SWI-Prolog, it is also possible to generate the Cartesian product using the [findall/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3) and [member/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=member/2) predicates:

```
:- initialization(main).
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

main :-
    product([1,2,3], [a,b], X),
    writeln(X).

product(A,B,C) :-
    findall([X,Y],(member(X,A),member(Y,B)),C).
```

This program prints `[[1,a],[1,b],[2,a],[2,b],[3,a],[3,b]]`.

Answer (score 2):

You should change the clause:

```
product([], [], [], []).
```

to:

```
product(_, [], [], _).
```

That's because when L2 gets empty it calls product(L1,[],L3,L4) where L1 and L4 are not empty. Your base case must be when L2 gets empty (then L3 gets empty as output list) and other lists may have elements:

```
?- product([1,2,3], [a,b], X).
X = [[1, a], [2, a], [3, a], [1, b], [2, b], [3, b]] ;
false.
```