# Combinations of multiple lists - Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I need to find the combinations in a list of lists. For example, give the following list,

```
List = [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

These should be the output,

```
Comb = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3]]
```

Another example:

```
List = [[1,2],[1,2],[1,2,3]]

Comb = [[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,1,3],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[1,2,3]....etc]
```

I know how to do it for a list with two sublists but it needs to work for any number of sublists.

I'm new to Prolog, please help.

Comment: `List = [[1,2],[1,2],[1,2,3]], bagof(Es, maplist(member,Es,List), Ess).`

Comment: @GuyCoder: how does your solution look like?

Comment: @GuyCoder: Any extension that is based on a system that itself is not very much conforming is certainly rather suspicious. In case of difficulties one would have to consult the expanded Prolog below.

Comment: @GuyCoder: So do you think that this would have been easy for OP?

Comment: @GuyCoder: A reminder: you offered a trade. And I fulfilled my part.

Answer (score 5):

This answer hunts the bounty offered "*for a pure solution that also takes into account for `Ess`*".
Here we generalize [this previous 
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60663083/4609915) like so:

```
list_crossproduct(Xs, []) :-
   member([], Xs).
list_crossproduct(Xs, Ess) :-
   Ess = [E0|_],
   same_length(E0, Xs),
   maplist(maybelonger_than(Ess), Xs),
   list_comb(Xs, Ess).

maybelonger_than(Xs, Ys) :-
   maybeshorter_than(Ys, Xs).

maybeshorter_than([], _).
maybeshorter_than([_|Xs], [_|Ys]) :-
   maybeshorter_than(Xs, Ys).
```

`list_crossproduct/2` gets bidirectional by relating `Xs` and `Ess` early.

```
?- list_comb(Xs, [[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,2,5]]).
nontermination                                % BAD!

?- list_crossproduct(Xs, [[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,2,5]]).
   Xs = [[1],[2],[3,4,5]]      % this now works, too
;  false.
```

Sample query having multiple answers:

```
?- list_crossproduct(Xs, [[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,2,5],X,Y,Z]).
   X = [1,2,_A],
   Y = [1,2,_B],
   Z = [1,2,_C], Xs = [[1],[2],[3,4,5,_A,_B,_C]]
;  X = [1,_A,3],
   Y = [1,_A,4],
   Z = [1,_A,5], Xs = [[1],[2,_A],[3,4,5]]
;  X = [_A,2,3],
   Y = [_A,2,4],
   Z = [_A,2,5], Xs = [[1,_A],[2],[3,4,5]]
;  false.
```

Comment: Of interest: better use `nilmemberd(Xs)` instead of `member([],Xs)`.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here is the augmented version of my comment-version. Note `nilmemberd_t/2` which is inspired by [`memberd_t/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22026153/772868).

```
nilmemberd_t([], false).
nilmemberd_t([X|Xs], T) :-
   if_(nil_t(X), T = true, nilmemberd_t(Xs, T)).

nil_t([], true).
nil_t([_|_], false).

list_comb(List, []) :-
   nilmemberd_t(List, true).
list_comb(List, Ess) :-
   bagof(Es, maplist(member,Es,List), Ess).
```

Above version shows that "only" the first clause was missing in my comment response.  Maybe even shorter with:

```
nilmemberd([[]|_]).
nilmemberd([[_|_]|Nils]) :-
   nilmemberd(Nils).
```

This should work for Prologs without constraints.  With constraints, bagof/3 would have to be reconsidered since copying constraints is an ill-defined terrain.

Comment: @rep: you mean you qualify for the promised bounty?

Comment: Nah! But I reckon I should post a lambda variant as a separate answer. (just 4 fun, not bounty worthy)

Comment: presumably, you did all these instead of just using `findall` instead of the `bagof`, to avoid the `findall( Es, maplist( member,Es, [[1,2],t,[1]]), Ess).` incorrectly succeeding with `[]` instead of  failing. but your version also similarly incorrectly succeeds with `[]` for `[[1,2],[],t,[1]]`.

Comment: I mean, because `bagof` incorrectly fails on `[[1,1],[],[1]]`, yet `findall` correctly (in this case) succeeds with `[]`.

Comment: @Will: `bagof/3` handles variables correctly whereas `findall/3` copies them like mad

Comment: `list_comb([[1,2],[],t,[1]],X).` 
`list_comb(T,[[1]]).`

Comment: That `list_comb(T,[[1]]).` loops is a much lesser problem than when it would fail, as looping cannot be interpreted as being true or false. And for `list_comb([[1,2],[],t,[1]],X).`: If you see this generalization as a problem, why do you then also choose to succeed for `list_comb([[1|non_list]],X)`? To me this appears as acceptable, But if you insist please throw in `maplist(maplist(\_^true), List)` at the end of both rules.

Comment: I've just tried `list_comb( [[1 | t]], X ).` with my code and *it properly fails as expected*.

Comment: @WillNess: Agreed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it using `maplist/3` and `append/2`:

```
list_comb([], [[]]).
list_comb([Xs|Xss], Ess) :-
   Xs = [_|_],
   list_comb(Xss, Ess0),
   maplist(aux_x_comb(Ess0), Xs, Esss1),
   append(Esss1, Ess).

aux_x_comb(Ess0, X, Ess1) :-
   maplist(head_tail_list(X), Ess0, Ess1).

head_tail_list(X, Xs, [X|Xs]).
```

Sample query:

```
?- list_comb([[a,b],[f,g],[x,y,z]], Ess).
Ess = [[a,f,x],[a,f,y],[a,f,z],
       [a,g,x],[a,g,y],[a,g,z],
       [b,f,x],[b,f,y],[b,f,z],
       [b,g,x],[b,g,y],[b,g,z]].
```

---

Here's how it works!
As an example, consider these goals:

- `list_comb([[a,b],[f,g],[x,y,z]], Ess)`
- `list_comb([      [f,g],[x,y,z]], Ess0)`

How can we get from `Ess0` to `Ess`?

1. We look at the answers to the 
   latter query:

   ```
   ?- list_comb([[f,g],[x,y,z]], Ess0).
   Ess0 = [[f,x],[f,y],[f,z], [g,x],[g,y],[g,z]].
   ```
2. ... place `a` before `[f,x]`, ..., `[g,z]` ...

   ```
   ?- maplist(head_tail_list(a),
              [[f,x],[f,y],[f,z],
               [g,x],[g,y],[g,z]], X).
   X = [[a,f,x],[a,f,y],[a,f,z],
        [a,g,x],[a,g,y],[a,g,z]].
   ```
3. ... then do the same for `b`.

   `maplist(aux_x_comb)` helps us handle all items:

   ```
   ?- maplist(aux_x_comb([[f,x],[f,y],[f,z],
                          [g,x],[g,y],[g,z]]),
              [a,b], X).
   X = [[[a,f,x],[a,f,y],[a,f,z],
         [a,g,x],[a,g,y],[a,g,z]],
        [[b,f,x],[b,f,y],[b,f,z],
         [b,g,x],[b,g,y],[b,g,z]]].
   ```
4. To get from a list of lists to a list use `append/2`.

I hope this explanation was more eludicating than confusing:)

Comment: `Ess` has no influence on termination - at least in some case

Answer (score 0):

A twist in @false's approach:

```erlang
%list_comb( ++LL, -Ess)
list_comb( LL, Ess):-
    is_list( LL),
    maplist( is_list, LL),
    findall( Es, maplist( member, Es, LL), Ess).
```

Testing:

> ```erlang
> 41 ?- list_comb( [[1,2],[1],[1]], X).
> X = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1]].
>
> 42 ?- list_comb( [[1,2],[1],[1,2,3]], X).
> X = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3]].
>
> 43 ?- list_comb( [[1,2],[],[1,2,3]], X).
> X = [].
>
> 44 ?- list_comb( [[1,2],t,[1,2,3]], X).
> false.
>
> 45 ?- list_comb( t, X).
> false.
> ```

Comment: By ruling out variables, the predicate becomes moded like a functional program - but without la... - er - non-strictness.