# Making tuples out of two lists

Tags: list, prolog

I'm a beginner in Prolog and I have two make tuples out of two lists using recursion. For example, func ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]) should output [(1, 4), (1,5), (1,6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3 ,5), (3, 6)]. I have the following code:

```
func([],_,[]).
func([X|T1],Y,[Z|W]):-
    match(X,Y,Z),
    func(T1,Y,W).

match(X,[Y],[(X,Y)]).
match(X,[Y|T],[(X,Y)|Z]) :-
    match(X,T,Z).
```

But my output for func([1,2,3],[4,5,6],X) is
X = [[(1, 4),  (1, 5),  (1, 6)], [(2, 4),  (2, 5),  (2, 6)], [(3, 4),  (3, 5),  (3, 6)]].

How can I get rid of the extra square brackets in the middle of my output? I've tried playing with the parenthesis and brackets in both of my functions, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: See similar question: [Combinations of multiple lists - Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60580822/1243762)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `findall/3` standard predicate and the `member/2` de facto standard predicate:

```
| ?- findall(X-Y, (member(X,[1,2,3]), member(Y,[4,5,6])), Pairs).

Pairs = [1-4,1-5,1-6,2-4,2-5,2-6,3-4,3-5,3-6]
yes
```

To understand this solution, observe that, for each value of `X`, we enumerate by backtracking all values of `Y`. I.e. when backtracking (as implicitly performed by the `findall/3` predicate to construct a list of all solutions of its second argument), we exhaust all solutions for the last choice-point (the `member(Y,[4,5,6])` goal) before backtracking to a previous choice-point (the `member(X,[1,2,3])` goal). This is know as *chronological backtracking* and is one of the defining characteristics of Prolog.

Note that I used `X-Y`, the usual Prolog representation for a *pair*, instead of `(X,Y)`, which is not a recommended solution for constructing n-tuples as it only works nicely for pairs of elements.